# python3.4 tkinter.scrolledtext not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I write this simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext

root = Tk()
textPad = tkinter.scrolledtext(root)
textPad.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But not run. output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/m/lale/test/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    textPad = tkinter.scrolledtext(root)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are almost there.  You need the ScrolledText class from the scrolledtext module.  This works.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

root = tk.Tk()
textPad = ScrolledText(root)
textPad.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.7 
following worked for me,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import scrolledtext
txt = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window,width=40,height=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Quick Script for using Tkinter / tkinter for Python 2.* & Python 3.***

I had a script which had different imports of Python 2.* Tkinter so browsing a but I see that the answer are all scattered. Here a small summary with a safe Script for using both Python versions.

```py
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as tkm
    import ScrolledText as tkst
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.messagebox as tkm
    import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

### List of ModuleNotFoundError Errors (When Running Python 3.)

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkMessageBox'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ScrolledText'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkFileDialog'
```